# How would I generalise this C# code into a more general method?

Tags: c#, delegates, types

I have numerous occurrences of the following in my code:

```
this.webBrowserCtrl.DocumentCompleted -= new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(this.LoginScreenLoaded);
this.webBrowserCtrl.DocumentCompleted += new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(this.AttemptLoginAnalysis);
```

I wish to remove this and use a simple method that takes 2 inputs - however I don't know what the types would be.

```
    private void DefineNewDocumentCompletedHandler(TYPEA inputA, TYPEB inputB)
    {

        this.webBrowserCtrl.DocumentCompleted -= new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(inputA);
        this.webBrowserCtrl.DocumentCompleted += new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(inputB);

    }
```

Does anyone know what TYPEA and TYPEB should be? Or another way to accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the delegate type on the input parameters, like this:

```
private void DefineNewDocumentCompletedHandler(WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler inputA, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler inputB)
{
    this.webBrowserCtrl.DocumentCompleted -= inputA;
    this.webBrowserCtrl.DocumentCompleted += inputB;
}
```

Example of use:

```
DefineNewDocumentCompletedHandler(this.LoginScreenLoaded, this.AttemptLoginAnalysis);
```

The syntax `new <delegate type>(<name of method>)` is a C# 1.x construct that is now obsolete. From C# 2.0 onwards, you can just specify the name of the method without parentheses, and the compiler will automatically wrap it in a delegate instance for you.

Comment: Thanks very much, especially for providing the actual code :-)

Answer (score 2):

TYPEA and TYPEB are of [WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowserdocumentcompletedeventargs.aspx)

Comment: __curious_geek - Thank you very much, if I could accept 2 answers I would accept yours too.

Answer (score 1):

You can also make an extension method of the method described by Christian.

```
public static void DefineNewDocumentCompletedHandler(this WebBrowser webBrowser, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler inputA, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler inputB)
{
webBrowser.webBrowserCtrl.DocumentCompleted -= inputA;
webBrowser.webBrowserCtrl.DocumentCompleted += inputB;
```

}

and use it like

```
this.webBrowserCtrl.DefineNewDocumentCompletedHandler(this.LoginScreenLoaded, this.AttemptLoginAnalysis);
```

Comment: thats a pretty nifty idea, unfortunately I need to target .net 2.0 - but thanks for the idea!